# how to use find command to get all the files in a directories starting with 'data' and 'user' in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, find

in the below list i want to retrieve files starting with data and user. need to retrieve from subdirectories also.

```
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jul 26 11:59 MIS
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jul 26 12:04 recommendations
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 11 07:45 script
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 11 08:40 log
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Sep 11 09:48 data_collection.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Sep 11 09:48 user_collection_12345.txt
```

Any help please?

Comment: @dogbane The *accepted* answer in the above link would give wrong results for the reason explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736686/2235132).

Answer (score 2):

This makes it:

```
find /your/dir   -type f   \( -name "data*"   -o -name "user*" \)
                 ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  files       either data...     or user...
```

Comment: This would also list **directories** starting with `user`.

Comment: @devnull thanks. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Hmm.. how different does it look from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736686/2235132) now?

Comment: I believe that here in [SO] it is common to help others if you detect some minimal error in their answer. It's what I got from yours, so I appreciated it, tested again and updated accordingly. Then I saw your answer. I don't think I have to be constrained because you added an answer in the meantime.